# Databricks delta live tables, when is it preferred to use and when not?

Tags: database, hive, devops, databricks, delta-live-tables

I'm using databricks to build most ML and data pipelines and replicate data from external data sources (e.g. cloud or snowflake) to hive (as a Delta table).

Before I ask the question I'll give two example use cases:

- Data is in a cloud object, the data gets updated on a monthly basis for example and I'd like to have a copy of the most recent date in Hive metastore.
- Data is in snowflake, also gets updated monthly and a most recent copy is needed in Hive.

So in both cases the pipeline that would update the data (either a DLT or a simple code that loads data from external sources and save it to Hive) will run monthly, and we're interested in overwriting the data, so replacing the old data with the most recent data each time.

From what I've read on DLTs, what I'm interested in most is data versioning but that should exist in regular delta tables. As I'm not doing any streaming, append only flows, pre-processing operations on multiple stages but rather simple load from sources and saving to Hive, does it still makes sense to makes this data extraction as part of a DLT instead of a regular pipeline (by regular pipeline I mean simple extraction/load code that is wrapped in a scheduled job) ?

Thank you for taking the time to read this.